# Can't select text inside div

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

The right column works perfectly, when I try to do the same with the left one it acts as if it was disabled.

I hope somebody can spot what's wrong here

http://jsfiddle.net/madprops/5HudT/3/

Comment: oops thanks for noticing that

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you set the `z-index` on `#leftblockreal`, it should be selectable:

```
#leftblockreal {
    left: 0;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/g_thom/5HudT/4/

Comment: you nailed it! but why is that required to the left one and not the right one?

Comment: I believe it's because #leftblockreal is 'below' #container in the stack. If you move #rightblockreal above #container, you won't be able to select it either. I.e., z-index allows you to affect the stack order.